# Filter values by text

Tags: r, filter, selection

I have 1578 path, stored as a values (character). I want choose just path which have "*/COU/*". Sorry, but i am quite new in R, and i have not found the answer yet.

my code:

```
files <- list.files("D:/*/", recursive=T)
```

and now i have list of 1578 files and i want choose only files, where part of path is "COU"

Best Regards!

I tried:
`files_selected <- filter(files, "*/COU/*")` and few another options (like subset) but it not work.

Comment: You may need `grep/grepl` instead of `filter` here i.t. `grep("/COU/", files, value = TRUE, fixed  = TRUE)`

Comment: or `list.files("D:/", pattern=".*COU.*", include.dirs = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)`